# Why FormSet saves the data of only one form in django2

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

When I submitted formset, my FormSet saves the data of only one form and other form data is lossed.

view.py:

```
def employadd(request):
    employ_academic_forms = EmployAcademicFormSet()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        employ_academic_forms = EmployAcademicFormSet(request.POST)
        if employ_academic_forms.is_valid():
                instances = employ_academic_forms.save(commit=False)
                for instance in instances:
                    instance.employ_id=employ_pass_obj
                    instance.save()
    context = {
        'employAcademicFormSet':employ_academic_forms,
    }
    return render(request, 'admins/employ/add_employ.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

I did solved this problem. This problem is no occur by django view function. Its will held for jquery script. I checked jquery script then i did solve it....